# Xcode opens xib File as regular text file

Tags: xcode

I have a Xcode project with .xib file. When I try to open them Xcode shows the plain text of these file, it does not show the Interface Builder Interface.

How can I make Xcode to show me what I want?

I have already cleaned the project and restarted my computer. Didn't help.

[image: Screenshot of Xcode showing xib file as plain text]

Please help me this.

Comment: If I changed the meaning of your question feel free to roll back the change in the edit history.

Comment: you should post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 36):

### Xcode 13, Xcode 14 (and maybe 11 and 12?)

The problem is that you are in ‘Code Review’ mode. Xcode has a button to toggle Code Review mode in the top right corner of the editor pane. It is an arrow pointing rightward above and arrow pointing leftward:

[image: top right corner of Xcode window with the Code Review button in its "on" state]

You can click the button to turn Code Review off:

[image: top right corner of Xcode window with the Code Review button in its "off" state]

You can also disable Code Review using the View > Hide Code Review menu item, which has the default shortcut <kbd>⌥⇧⌘⏎</kbd> (option shift command return).

### Xcode 9 and Earlier

The problem is that you have the version editor selected.

Xcode 6: [image: version editor selected] … Xcode 9: [image: version editor selected]

The version editor can only display source code.  It can't display a xib graphically.  You need to switch to the standard editor.  Here are three ways to switch to the standard editor:

- Press Command-Return.
- Go to the menu bar and choose View > Standard Editor > Show Standard Editor.
- Click the leftmost button in the “Editor” segmented control in the toolbar:

Xcode 6: [image: standard editor selected] … Xcode 9: [image]

Answer (score 3):

On the .xib file in the list of files, you can right-click and select Open As... and choose Source Code or Interface Builder.

Comment: Did you try to look a bit closer at his screenshot? It shows his cursor above the "open-as" entry which shows no further options.

Comment: Wow. I completely missed that. Thanks @Till for pointing it out.